# Convert huge spring xml configuration to java based configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the project that has very huge legacy spring xml configuration (about 500 beans).

This configuration is too difficult to support.

The best way is convert xml to java based configuration, but it difficult to do manualy.

Is anybody known any tools for automatically convertaion Spring xml configuration to Spring java based configuration?

Comment: I don't think there are people who are that negligent, and also people with free time to create one. I'm sure someone will happily take that project for a price and create utility to put @Component in all files that are declared as beans. Every negligence has a price.